# Auto-install Eclipse Lombok plugin - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lombok

We just started using Lombok plugin for Java. 
Developers in our company use Eclipse for workspace and we have some clients who get access to part of our source code.

If we use Lombok library, it doesn't get detected in Eclipse until the plugin is manually installed.

It's hard to send a communication to multiple clients and have them mandate the plugin installation.

Is there a way to automatically install a plugin from the project itself, may be with an yes/no question to let the users accept it, that way we don't get accused of sneaking stuff in :)

Comment: Use the maven dependency in the pom.xml: https://projectlombok.org/mavenrepo/index.html

Comment: Maven dependency will add the jar and it will work fine on the server. But it still is a problem with Eclipse detecting the library until the plugin is manually installed.

Comment: Update: now you can install the plugin directly from eclipse. Please follow instructions on https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT possible to install an Eclipse plugin from the project itself.

It is clearly stated in the Lombok documentation that manual installation is necessary as Lombok is a **preprocessor**. Lombok needs to be installed to the Eclipse install folder (next to eclipse.ini). https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

And I suppose it would be a security leak (both in Eclipse and your Customer's environment) if you are able to install something into the 'Program Files' folder from your projects without user interaction. However manually copying is feasible and could be a workaround if you are very keen to do so.

*Workaround:* You might provide an ANT/GRADLE script that will distribute you local copy of the lombok.jar into Eclipse's program folder. And also create a launcher configuration. So you can refer to this launcher step to be executed. Please note that you need to **restart eclipse just after lombok installed**. But in fact this is what lombok.jar does when running as described in the install guide.

Answer (score 0):

The standard lombok installation is being done manually.
Therefore, I've created an automatic installer.
It's available here: https://github.com/zorik9/lombok-automatic-installer
Right now it supports only eclipse IDE in windows machine.

The idea is to configure once the variables: lombok_version, eclipse_home and workspace_dir (not mandatory)

And based on this configuration, run the installation script on each machine.

For more details, please read the readme.md file.